# Python & memory mapping?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Using a Linux machine, how many files can one 'mmap' using python (what is the limit)?
Thanks.

Comment: How many files can one 'mmap' using linux API's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's multiple limits in play. The first is the system-wide open files limit, `/proc/sys/fs/nr_open`. This is typically in the million-range.

This limit may continue to be counted against processes that open the file, set up the mapping, then close the file again.

The second is the per-process `getrlimit(2)` `RLIMIT_NOFILE` per-process number of open files. This limit is typically in the 1024-range.

This limit appears to be on the highest file descriptor that will be allocated to the process, so it probably *won't* continue to be counted against processes that open the file, set up the mapping, then close the file again.

The third is the amount of address space available to the process (`getrlimit(2)` `RLIMIT_AS` *and* architecture-dependent (2, 3, or maybe 4 gigabytes (with the 4:4 address space patch) on 32-bit, or many many gigabytes on 64-bit). 3 gigabytes is typical on x86, and due to address space layout issues, you'll have probably 2.5 gigs available for `mmap`.

Clever use of `fork(2)` could let you set up one process per mapped file, and have gigabytes upon gigabytes mapped simultaneously even on 32-bit processors, but the `getrlimit(2)` `RLIMIT_NPROC` number of processes per user limitation may limit you to a maximum number of open processes, and thus files.

Comment: sarnold, thank you! such a detailed answer. Can you elaborate on: "Clever use of `fork(2)` could let you set up one process per mapped file, and have gigabytes upon gigabytes mapped simultaneously even on 32-bit processors" ?

Comment: @user540009, it would basically be `fork()`ing a bunch of helper programs, and each one would `mmap(2)` their own file. Then your master program would send commands to the helper processes through a `pipe(2)` and read results back on another `pipe(2)`. Depending upon the processing required, this might make excellent use of multi-core CPUs, or it might be a ton of useless overhead. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is completely system dependent.

This limit won't be imposed by python, rather it will be dependent on your OS settings and the amount of memory you have available. Furthermore, your system may impose a per process mmap limit which you can check at `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count`.